# Web Api2 and protected setters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've got an entity which I pull directly from the database using EF that looks like this:

```
public class MyEntity : EntityBase {
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

where as `EntityBase` looks like the following

```
public abstract class EntityBase {
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
}
```

The reason the `Id` is protected is simple: It shouldn't be changed at any state. This works fine with EF (I assume it uses reflection to set the value?), however when I send a `POST` from a client with the model data via my web api, the `Id` is always 0 (default). Is there a way to access protected setters with Web API 2? Or do I have to map it manually from a DTO?

Comment: Yes, it's better to accept view models from API requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your client tries to create a MyEntity it should know nothing about id since it's not relevant at creation state. It just knows that new entity will have MyProperty set to "some value". I prefer to work with dto and they should contain only request related information.

For mapping I'd suggest to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: In Addition. Rather than view models, probably use dtos. More a semantics thing, but because API is about specific entities it makes more sense. MVC was more view model centric due collating all data together